# C#: Multiple handlers with different generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to implement some handler logic, based on the type of a parameter. Take for example, implementing an exception filter attribute for WebAPI:

```
public class ExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
    }
}
```

This looks perfectly fine on its own, but what I would like to do, is add several handlers for different types of exceptions, e.g. `DbEntityValidationException`, or some other custom exceptions that my business logic may throw.

Now of course, I could easily add another `if`-block to check if the exception is a certain type, but I would rather avoid this and break out the handling of different exception types into separate classes.

An interface for such a class might look like this

```
public interface ExceptionHandler<T> where T : Exception {
    void Handle(HttpActionExecutedContext context, T exception);
}
```

I would now like to add the implementations of these `ExceptionHandler`s into a collection in the `ExceptionFilterAttribte`, so I can check if there is a handler for the exception that was encountered and do the appropriate casting and call the handler. However, I can not figure out, how I would have to implement this part, since I cannot add implementations of the `ExceptionHandler` interface with different generic types `T` into a single collection (e.g. `class DbEntityValidationExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler<DbEntityValidationException>`):

```
    private List<ExceptionHandler<Exception>> handlers = new List<ExceptionHandler<Exception>>()
    {
        new DbEntityValidationExceptionHandler() // does not compile...
    };
```

How can I keep references to the different implementations of my `ExceptionHandler<T>` interface in a collection? Or is this approach completely misguided and there is a much better way of handling this type of situation? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a non-generic interface with a `Handle` method that takes a generic constraint type (`Exception`) that they implement, and make the collection of that type.

Comment: You can't.  Generics aren't the be-all-end-all.  Most everything generic in the framework implements a non-generic form of its interface (e.g., IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable for all collections). It all boils down to the fact that Something<Hurf> is a different type than Something<Durf>. You can't handle multiple types the same way unless they share a common base type or interface.

Comment: @Will thanks for your comment. Just out of curiosity, how would you go about implementing such behavior, other than just adding `if` blocks for each type of exception to be handled?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. Can you expand?

Comment: I usually design things so that I can add more of them that behave differently without changing any other code.  So I'd do something similar to how @BradleyUffner describes.  `public abstract class ExceptionHandler { public abstract void Handle(Exception ex); }` let the handler determine if it wants to handle a particular exception.

Comment: @Will Thanks, this is how I ended up implementing this. It seems like that's the best I can do in this case. However I somewhat dislike the individual type checking and casting I have to do in each of the handlers. I usually like to hide such lower level logic behind an interface, hence my attempt in this question.

Comment: I know. It's the one shortcoming of generic types--you can't handle them generically :)

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with Variant Generic Interface

```
class TestException : Exception
{
}
class TestException2:Exception
{
}

class foo : ExceptionHandler<TestException> { }
class bar : ExceptionHandler<TestException2> { }

public interface ExceptionHandler<out T> where T : Exception
{ }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ExceptionHandler<Exception>> a = new List<ExceptionHandler<Exception>>();
        a.Add(new foo());
        a.Add(new bar());
    }

}
```

Comment: Had to read up on that one - but are you sure 'out' is right, given the likely method you'd want will take T as an input parameter (e.g. "void HandleException(T exception)") ?  And I'm curious as to how it would then actually work - if all you have is a List<ExceptionHandler<Exception> > and an Exception object, how would you obtain the matching handler and pass it the exception safely downcast to the right class?

Comment: @DylanNicholson yes out is the right one to use here. Since it is the only way to down cast generic interface to <Exception>. What OP could do is to add a field that will return type T to see if the current handler can handle the given exception, and the HandleException function will take in (Exception e)

Comment: @Steve thanks for pointing this out. I was not aware of the `out` keyword yet. Although I think for my case this does not work as @DylanNicholson points out, I'd need to use the generic type as a method argument.

Comment: I'd actually say you're better using dynamic dispatch. That way you can declare overloaded functions that handle each exception type, and have the correct one picked at runtime by storing in a 'dynamic' var.